# React-Native Video Play in Default Player

Tags: android, iphone, react-native, video-player

I want to **play video** in default player like **MxPlayer** or **Vlc** in **Android or Iphone both using React native**. I am new in React native, i have search on net but cant fine any solution!

I want to do it just like via Intent in Android.

Please let me know if anyone know anything.

Thank You Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this npm module. It will open the audio/video using intent in android. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-native-video-player